# How to implement RichTextBox or Avalonedit with RuleLine (muted lines) in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, richtextbox, avalonedit

I wanna implement an editor that requires drawing RuleLines(Muted lins?) per line like the ones in the image below.
I'm going to use `RichTextBox` or AvalonEdit.

Can you help me creating this pattern?
Thanks in advance..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF `RichTextBox` you can set border thickness for the `Paragraph` style. It will look like on your screenshot.

```cs
<RichTextBox x:Name="richtextbox" >   
    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#388FFA"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Resources>
</RichTextBox>
```

[image]

Comment: this is what i wanna,but richtextbox input is very laggy in wpf

Answer (score 0):

I've done it in AvalonEdit by myself.
add RulerLines(just need drawline via DrawingContext) class when VisualLine or TextView Rendering.
[Image Done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VI3B.png)

Comment: This answer isn't clear - can you please [edit] it to clarify your solution in steps, and either embed your linked image and/or explain what it is in your link rather than "Image Done".  You may find helpful info [on how to answer in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).